# Why Voldemort did not care about significance of some of this murders during horcrux making?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, horcrux

While reading threads here, it has been established that not all murders had significance for Voldemort  (Albanian peasant, Hepzibbah Smith). They were pretty much holders/middle roads to obtaining items for future horcruxes. Excluding cases where Voldemort did not have the luxury to make horcrux in significant murder: Harry (unintentionally), Nagini (did not have a proper body), here is my question:

**Why did Voldemort not care about the significance of some of his murders when he was in full power? Why couldn't he obtain items, hold them until someone significant appears, and make a horcrux then?**

I am asking because he initially made horcruxes only for something significant: Myrtle - first murder significance, indication on stepping into a dark path, parents - no need to comment, Marvolo - same deal. Why did he stop caring mid-road?

Comment: What do you mean he stopped caring? Are you asking why he didn't make a horcrux for every murder?

Comment: @NKCampbell No, I am saying that initially he created horcruxes for significant killings, but somewhere mid-road, where he was in full power, he created them with killing of some insignificant people (peasant, old woman). Why did he stop caring about significance midway, when he could grab items and make them into horcruxes when someone significant shows up.

Comment: hmm - actually, imo, the only murder that actually seemed to have any real emotional significance would be the second one, which was w/ the murder of his father. Every other one seems to have simply been whatever was most expedient. Voldemort didn't kill Marvolo or Morfin